# Strict convexity of a function

Tags: convex-optimization

How to prove that for each $\alpha > 1$ the function $\psi(t)=|t|^\alpha$ is strictly convex on the real line?

Comment: Note that $\psi$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Then use the fact that a differentiable function is strictly convex if and only if its derivative is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

You can see $\psi$ as a composition of two functions, namely $x \mapsto |x|$ and $x \mapsto x^{\alpha}$ the first one is convex, and the second one is strictly convex , and increasing. Hence the result.

Comment: Notice that every constant function, say $f(x) = c \ge 0$, is convex. But $f^{\alpha}$ isn't strictly convex.

Comment: @W.314 why is $x^\alpha$ strictly convex?

Comment: @roc11111111 $x^{\alpha}$  is strictly convex for $ x \geq 0$ since its derivative $\alpha x ^{\alpha - 1}$ is increasing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct proof. Let $x_1$, $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ ($x_1 \neq x_2$), and let $0<\theta<1$. We have:
$$\begin{align}
|\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2 |^\alpha &\leq (|\theta x_1| + |(1-\theta) x_2 |)^\alpha \\
& < |\theta x_1|^\alpha + |(1-\theta) x_2 |^\alpha \\
& = \theta^\alpha | x_1|^\alpha + (1-\theta)^\alpha |x_2 |^\alpha \\
& < \theta| x_1|^\alpha + (1-\theta) |x_2 |^\alpha.
\end{align}$$